# Can workbooks uploaded to Tableau Public have filters?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working with a Tableau workbook that contains a list of checkboxes the user can choose among. When I view the workbook in Tableau Desktop, I can enable filters to allow me to search by keyword, rather than scrolling down the long list of checkboxes:

[image]

However, when I upload the workbook to Tableau Public, there is no filter that appears above the checkboxes:

[image]

I checked the settings in Tableau Public, and I don't see an option to enable/disable filters:

[image]

Is this feature available in Tableau Public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and want to share it with folks who may come across this post.

The solution can be found in the "Edit Filter" menu, which you can access by clicking the arrow icon at the top of your list of items:

[image]

The workbook I had been using had the option "Use all" checked. When I switched to "Select from list" and republished the workbook to Tableau Public, I discovered that the filter option became available:

[image]

Again, hope this will be helpful for a future reader.